# React - useState not updating unless class object is duplicated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state using the useState hook for React. However, I think I am using it incorrectly or at least not how it's intended.

I have a class which is initialised.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(new Form());
```

I am then adding elements to this form:

```
const element = ...

setForm(form => ({
  ...form,
  elements: [
    ...form.elements,
    element
  ]
});
```

However, this doesn't seem to update the UI to reflect this change.

I have also tried the following:

```
setForm(form => {
  form.elements.push(element);
  return form;
});
```

The only way I can get it to work is doing the following and as you can imagine it becomes quite a mountain to climb as it's a bit all over the place:

```
const duplicated = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(form));
duplicated.elements.push(element);
setForm(new Form(duplicated));
```

Is there a better approach to do this rather than having to duplicate the object everytime.

Comment: we would need to see a bit more of your component to give a certain PoV, for one, new Form() may not be returning what you think it is returning (we don't know what its constructor is either), also it's not clear what's triggering the `setForm`, I would rather keep an eye on elements.

Comment: I've tested a similar code with my own Form class implementation and the setForm() call inside an onClick handler, and works perfectly for me. I subscribe @WistonCoronell 's comment. I would just add that your "push" approach is wrong. Use the first approach which seems to be correct anyway.

Comment: I dont know if this helps but destructuring only copies the first level of an object, it doesnt deeply copies, maybe why the JSON.stringify works.